# Execute function across user controls wpf c#

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a MainWindow in my application.
Within the MainWindow I dynamically host a user control (ucA).
Within ucA i have another user control (ucB).

When I click the save button on ucB, i need to execute a routine on ucA.

How can I reference the routine on ucA?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways I can think of :-

You can use `CallMethodAction` in your xaml to call a method of parent usercontrol. The code  goes like this :-

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.ucB"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
     Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Save" x:Name="SaveButton" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                MethodName="MethodToCallOnucA" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>        

</StackPanel>
```

This way you can call the method on ucA which is the parent of ucB. BUT there is a big limitation to this way of calling methods from xaml. The limitation is that in this case your `MethodToCallOnucA' must return void and must have no method parameters.

If you **must** send parameters to your method then you need to follow the SECOND approach over here. For this we need to use Commands to make a call to method of Usercontrol. You need to change the button's code in the xaml above like this :-

```
<Button Content="Save" x:Name="SaveButton" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DoActionCommand}" CommandParameter="ValueToSendAsMethodParameter" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
```

Here DoActionCommand is a ICommand property defined in your usercontrol ucA and this ICommand points to the method you need to call in ucA.

Comment: Will give this a try.
Looking forward to testing this.